# How can i store for loop print value in variable or list

Tags: python, pokeapi

I am actually new to python and just started learning it i am working with an module which is based on [Pokeapi](https://pokeapi.co/) and its name is [Pokebase](https://github.com/PokeAPI/pokebase) which is basically a python wrapper for that api so I am having a problem with it:
Here's a for loop in which I print some data recieved by the api.
**Code:**

```
import pokebase as pb
p1=pb.pokemon('charmander')
for stat in p1.stats:
    print('{}: {}'.format(stat.stat.name, stat.base_stat))
```

actually I dont want to print this value I want to save this value in a variable or list how can i do that?

Comment: ```[[stat.stat.name, stat.base_stat] for stat in p1.stats]```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save it in a list:

```
[[stat.stat.name, stat.base_stat] for stat in p1.stats]
```

This is called a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

If you want to use a dictionary:

```
{stat.stat.name: stat.base_stat for stat in p1.stats}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it!

```py
import pokebase as pb
p1=pb.pokemon('charmander')
names = []
base_stats = []
for stat in p1.stats:
    #print('{}: {}'.format(stat.stat.name, stat.base_stat))
    names.append(stat.stat.name)
    base_stats.append(stat.base_stat)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```py
import pokebase as pb
p1 = pb.pokemon('charmander')

stats = []
for stat in p1.stats:
   stats.append( '{}: {}'.format(stat.stat.name, stat.base_stat) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I guess:

```
stat_str = ""
for stat in p1.stats:
    stat_str += f"{stat.stat.name}: {stat.base_stat}\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Python Noob and there is undoubtedly a better solution but this works:

```
import pokebase as pb

p1 = pb.pokemon('charmander')

p1Dictionary = {}

for stat in p1.stats:
    p1Dictionary.update({stat.stat.name : stat.base_stat}) 
print(p1Dictionary)
for key, value in p1Dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```